# How do I correctly call a post method to twitch api?

Tags: c#, json, xamarin, twitch

i am working on a projected connected to twitch login. when i look at their documentation on how to setup it up this is what it says:

```
POST https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/oauth2/token

POST Body (URL-encoded)
client_id=<your client ID>
&client_secret=<your client secret>
&grant_type=authorization_code
&redirect_uri=<your registered redirect URI>
&code=<authorization code received above>
&state=<your unique token generated by your application>
```

https://dev.twitch.tv/docs/v5/guides/authentication/#implicit-grant-flow
(i am following the "Authorization Code Flow" guide).

however i currently have some problem making it work. this is what my code looks like:

```
    static public async Task getTwitchData()
    {
        var httpClientRequest = new HttpClient();

        var postData = new Dictionary<string, object>();
        postData.Add("client_id", clientId);
        postData.Add("client_secret", secretId);
        postData.Add("grant_type", accesstoken);
        postData.Add("redirect_uri", redirectURL);
        postData.Add("code", accesstoken);
        postData.Add("state", mycreatedtoken);

        var jsonRequest = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(postData);
        HttpContent content = new StringContent(jsonRequest, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

        var result = await httpClientRequest.PostAsync("https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/oauth2/token", content);
        try
        {
            var resultString = await result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            var jsonResult = JObject.Parse(resultString);
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(jsonResult);
            return jsonResult;
        }

        catch
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(result);
            return null;
        }
    }
```

if i run this function it does not reach "try" because it cannot find json. instead it reaches the "catch" where this gets printed out:

```
StatusCode: 400, ReasonPhrase: 'Bad Request', Version: 1.1, Content:  System.Net.Http.StreamContent, Headers:
```

and what i should get (if done correct) is a response in json looking like this:

```
{
"access_token": "<user access token>",
"scope": <your previously listed scope(s)>
}
```

Comment: Are you sending your request over https?

Comment: yeah I use the 'Microsoft.Net.Http' framework. In the start of the code you can see how i use it: `var httpClientRequest = new HttpClient();`

Comment: Have you enabled ssl in debug mode though? The httpclient class will use whatever protocol you've set up your application to use. I ask because most oauth2 implementations will force you to use https, although they should tell you that in your returned error message instead of giving you a 400...

Comment: i am writing this code for an app and it is also from the app where i use this code. i have not heard of ssl before, i will google it and check it out to see

Comment: i saw an exact post going through what you mentioned about ssl: https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/34678/xamarin-forms-app-cannot-connect-with-ssl-web-api seems like there can be some issues. i am now testing on a "simulator" and not a real device so that might be the issue.

Comment: Bad request means that the twitch server received something unexpected so it could be an ssl problem but it could also be malformed json or an invalid redirect uri or something else, I would check these things too

Comment: If you are making these requests from a mobile app, you should be using Implicit Grant Flow not Authorization Code Flow. Authorization Code Flow is for accessing Twitch from your server, not a mobile app.

Comment: yes, that was the issue! thanks a lot for pointing that out :) if you want you can make an answer and i will upvote it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Use the **Implicit Grant Flow** if your app **does not** use a server, such as a client-side JavaScript app or mobile app. This approach does not require a server that must make requests to the API.

If you are making these requests from a mobile app, you should be using `Implicit Grant Flow` not `Authorization Code Flow`.

Authorization Code Flow is for accessing Twitch from your server, not a mobile app.

Re: https://dev.twitch.tv/docs/v5/guides/authentication/